# Pros and cons of requiring disjointness of Hom sets in categories: Reference?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Hom sets in categories are often assumed to be disjoint.

Here are the pros and cons of requiring disjointness of Hom sets in categories:

**Pros**

- Given any morphism $f$, one could unambiguously determine the domain and codomain of $f$.
- Having a single class of morphisms defined without "tagging" with the domain and codomain naturally generalizes to internal categories in categories with pullbacks.

**Cons**

- One would have to annoyingly attach the domain and codomain to the definition of a morphism in many interesting categories (e.g., a morphism $f:X \to Y$ in the category of sets would be a triple $(X, Y, G)$ where $G$ is the graph of $f$ rather than just $G$ itself).
- Disjointness is "evil" (not invariant under isomorphisms of sets).
- Disjointness is not even defined in general monoidal categories used to define enriched categories.

But are there any sources on category theory mentioning the pros and cons of requiring disjointness of Hom sets like the ones above?

Comment: Why is the (excellent!) answer by Qiaochu not accepted yet?

Answer (score 7):

> One would have to annoyingly attach the domain and codomain to the definition of a morphism in many interesting categories

This is not a con, you should be doing this anyway. The domain and codomain are simply part of the data of a morphism.

> (e.g., a morphism $f:X \to Y$ in the category of sets would be a triple $(X, Y, G)$ where $G$ is the graph of $f$ rather than just $G$ itself)

That *is* what a morphism in the category of sets is. You *cannot* define a morphism in the category of sets to just be the graph of a function; the graph of a function doesn't know what its codomain is, only its range.

> Disjointness is "evil" (not invariant under isomorphisms of sets).

Category theorists do not think of sets as having elements that can be meaningfully compared to each other at all; that is, to a category theorist, it simply does not make sense to take the intersection of two sets at all (since this concept is not invariant under isomorphism of sets). This is formalized by [structural set theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory) such as [ETCS](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS), where we axiomatize the behavior of sets and functions rather than sets and membership (as is done in [material set theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/material+set+theory) such as ZFC).

So it's not that we require homsets to be disjoint, it's that to a category theorist it's not even a meaningful question. We simply never perform any operations that would be sensitive to the difference, in the same way that in analysis we never perform any operations on real numbers that are sensitive to the exact sets used to build real numbers in ZFC (which are different if you use Cauchy sequences vs. Dedekind cuts, for example). These are "implementation details."

Do you worry about whether the sets $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$ (these are sets in ZFC, since everything is a set!) are disjoint? If not you shouldn't worry about this either.

> Disjointness is not even defined in general monoidal categories used to define enriched categories.

Sure it is; as long as you're worrying about whether sets are disjoint, every monoidal category you've ever written down has objects which are constructed out of sets in some way, so in ZFC their objects are all literally sets. This is both "evil" and a pointless thing to worry about but so is the original question about sets!